# How to use regex with pandas.Series.str.replace()

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to replace specific parts of a string with the pandas.Series.str.replace() method using regex to define the parts I want to change, according to the docs you can use regular expressions and even re.compile objects. I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong but I just seem to erasing completely, instead of replacing parts of the string.

So in my DataFrame let's say I have a column called ['dates'], which is formatted like this:

```
'2016-03-26 17:47:46'
```

I just want to grab the dashes, space and the time (leaving the 8 digits as a date) - then replace them with '' hopefully leaving 20160326, so I make an re.compile object which grabs those:

```
re_express = re.compile('[\d]{4}(.)[\d]{2}(.)[\d]{2}(.*)')
```

Then I attempt replacing them with this line:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(re_express,'')
```

Unfortunately this just erases the date completely, leaving '' in my ['dates'] column. These re.compile objects are accepted according to the docs, if I used re.findall() then that regex string would grab the parts I want from that date, so I can only assume I cannot use them the same way in this method. It there an adjustment I can make to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your regex matches the entire string, so the entire string is replaced by the empty string. Instead what you need is to capture the numbers of interest in your string and replace the match with the captured values of the dates:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-03-26 17:47:46', '2018-03-26 17:47:46']})
re_express = re.compile('([\d]{4}).([\d]{2}).([\d]{2}).*')
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(re_express, r'\1\2\3')
```

Note the `r'\1\2\3'` part that refers to the first, second and third capture group respectively, which (using the modified pattern) refer to exactly the values you're interested in. If the strings can only ever contain hyphens between the date components then I'd suggest matching exactly that (`-`) rather than any character (`.`).

---

If you *really* want to stick with the "match and delete" approach, you could write a regex to catch "a hyphen or anything starting with a space":

```
re_express = re.compile('-| .*')
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(re_express, '')
```

But explicit is better than implicit, and the former method will more reliably ensure that malformed data won't silently be truncated in unexpected ways.